# Confusion about Find And Replace

Tags: c#, replace

Hi I am trying to find and replace  string.The problem is that `String.Replace` function needs two parametres for oldvalue and new value .I need something like that

```
 (content, textBox1.Text, textBox1.Text)
```

I have tried using `Regex` but It didnt work

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        openFileDialog1.Filter = "All Files|*.*|Images Files(*.jpeg)|*.jpeg";
        //openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;

        DialogResult dr = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
        {


                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName, Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1254"));
                string content = sr.ReadToEnd();

                sr.Close();

                content = Regex.Replace(content, textBox1.Text, textBox1.Text);

                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(content);
                sw.Write(content);
                sw.Close();



            }

        }
```

Comment: ok.Basiclly how can i run this code :))

Comment: Ha,ha.. no serious, what do you want to achieve with the replace method ? What do you want to find and why do you need 3 parameters for the String.Replace() where 2 are identical (textBox1.Text ) ?

Comment: OK, you want to replace `textBox1.Text` with `textBox1.Text`. You can do that by putting `//` in front of the Replace() statement.

Comment: ok.value comes from first texbox is for searching second texbox is for replace that string . there is no ReplaceText command that can open a text file and find and replace text.How Can I Find and Replace Text in a Text File?

Comment: Reading a .jpg with 1254 Encoding into a string?! What black magic are you trying to do? And how exactly do you think a replace with three parameters (two of which are the same: `textBox1.Text`) should work? A "normal" replace works like this: `var someString = "Hello World!".Replace("World", "Universe");` now `someString` is equal to `"Hello Universe!"`.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `content = content.Replace(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);`. Btw. in your example, there is no second textbox.

Answer (score 3):

What do you want to replace with what? string.Replace works fine, but you're replacing textBox1.Text with itself, which would obviously result in the same string. You'd need something like this:

```
content = content.Replace(the-value-you-want-to-replace, the-value-you-want-to-replace-it-with);
```